# Make single record to multiple records in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a records look like below

[image]

From two rows, I want to split ShiftPattern values and create multiple records and StartWeek will be created sequentially.

Final Query:

1. Split ShiftPattern Column and Create multiple records
2. Increase StartWeek like as 20, 21 to rotation.

**Output result**

[image]

Comment: How many shift patterns are there?  Is that number consistent?

Comment: and are they fixed length?

Comment: If shift pattern is 1006 then rotation 20 and for 1008 rotation 21. Am i getting you correct?

Comment: hmm, but it is not fixed, will be generated dynamically.

Comment: @LoztInSpace, no fixed length, it can be 1006,1008,1004,1005

Comment: So rotation  output will be if 1006,1008,1004,1005

Comment: What is the rotation output will be if shift pattern is 1006,1008,1004,1005??

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need. Tested in fiddle.

<kbd>**[`SQLFiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ebec/2)**</kbd>

```
select q.locationid,q.employeeid, 
case 
when (lag(employeeid,1,null) over (partition by employeeid order by weekshiftpatternid)) is null
 then startweek 
 else startweek + 1 
end as rotation ,
q.weekshiftpatternid,
q.shiftyear
 from 
(
select locationid,employeeid, left(d, charindex(',', d + ',')-1) as weekshiftpatternid ,
startweek,shiftyear
from (
    select *, substring(shiftpattern, number, 200) as d from MyTable locationid left join
        (select distinct number from master.dbo.spt_values where number between 1 and 200) col2
        on substring(',' + shiftpattern, number, 1) = ','
    ) t 
) q
```

Output

```
+------------+------------+----------+--------------------+-----------+
| locationid | employeeid | rotation | weekshiftpatternid | shiftyear |
+------------+------------+----------+--------------------+-----------+
|          1 |   10000064 |       20 |               1006 |      2016 |
|          1 |   10000064 |       21 |               1008 |      2016 |
|          1 |   10000065 |       20 |               1006 |      2016 |
|          1 |   10000065 |       21 |               1008 |      2016 |
+------------+------------+----------+--------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: great. after complete checking i will mark your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Similar:
In my test table my ID is your `EmployeeID` or however you want to work it.

```
SELECT  
*,
LEFT(shiftBits, CHARINDEX(',', shiftBits + ',')-1) newShiftPattern,
StartWeek+ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY shiftBits ) as newStartWeek
FROM
(
SELECT  
SUBSTRING(shiftPattern, number, LEN(shiftPattern)) AS shiftBits,
test2.*
FROM 
test2,master.dbo.spt_values 
WHERE 
TYPE='P' AND number<LEN(shiftPattern)
AND SUBSTRING(',' + shiftPattern, number, 1) = ','
) AS x
```